# Puppeteer: Not able to take full page screenshot in headful mode

Tags: puppeteer

Not able to see the correct screenshot in `headless: false` mode but getting the correct screenshot with `headless: true` configuration.

Run this script:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  });

  await page.goto(
    "https://pastebin.com/XcHLqyNC",
    {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      timeout: 0
    }
  );

  await page.screenshot({
    path: "check-this-screenshot.png",
    fullPage: true
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4500

Comment: FYI: Your script runs fine for me and generates a screenshot of the page (Windows 10).

Comment: thanks, @ThomasDondorf for the confirmation, Haven't tried it on windows but I can reproduce the issue on OSx 10.14 and Ubuntu 18.x